# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, model

when i was trying to create database tables using EF core it is showing error
error is
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_PRDetails_PR_Prid' on table 'PRDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Below is my Model classes.

PR.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace InventoryManagement.Models
{
    public class PR
    {
        [Key]
        public int Prid { get; set; }
        public DateTime Prdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Prcreateddate { get; set; }

        // Navigation property for one-to-many relationship
        public List<PRDetails> PRDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and
PrDetails.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace InventoryManagement.Models
{
    public class PRDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int Prtblid { get; set; }
        public double Prqty { get; set; }

        // Foreign key property
  

  public int Prid { get; set; }

    // Navigation property for the relationship
    [ForeignKey("Prid")]
    public PR PR { get; set; }

    public Bom Bom { get; set; }
}
```

}

here Prid is primary key of PR and it is refering as foreign key in PRDetails

while trying to update database using command it is showing below error
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_PRDetails_PR_Prid' on table 'PRDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try add following code to your dbcontext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (modelBuilder == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");

    // for the other conventions, we do a metadata model loop
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        entityType.SetTableName(entityType.DisplayName());

        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        entityType.GetForeignKeys()
            .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(fk => fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Or modify PRDetails.cs like this:

```
...
        [ForeignKey("PR")]
        public int Prid { get; set; }
        [DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)]
        public PR PR { get; set; }
...
```

Reference: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/change-delete-behavior-and-more-on-ef-core/